# Render dynamic HTML in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a component called "dishes" in which I have an option to get the recipe details of the selected dish from a microservice.

microservice actually returns the recipe details in html format.
Once I get recipe details I want to use the same HTML response to render in **RecipePage**.

I tried to hold the response in a global variables and tried to use the same to render in **RecipePage**

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Dish Recipe</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  {{htmlRecipe}}//a global variable that holds the recipe details
</ion-content>
```

It neither shows up any content in htmlpage nor any error. When I try to log the content in console log says *undefined*

How to just render the dynamic html page with out any modifications?

Comment: It seems that the value of `htmlRecipe` always remains `undefined`. Can you show the code when the data is fetched ?

Comment: Yeah, I did some changes in the code now am able to get the html content. 
and I changed the RecipePage.html as 
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item >
    <ion-label [innerHTML]="htmlRecipe">
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
however html content also has style part which is not properly being rendered.

meaning that all the style part is just displayed as text on the screen.

Comment: try:` <ion-content> <div [innerHTML]="htmlRecipe"><div> </ion-content>`

Comment: Yes I tried this, It works well, but style part of html in head part of HTML, is not being read or rendered properly.
when I read style part is shown as raw in the resultant screen